# Which of the two PostgreSQL indexes is more efficient?

Tags: database, performance, postgresql, indexing, query-optimization

I have the following PostgreSQL schema:

```
CREATE TABLE User (
    ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE BOX (
    ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY 
);

CREATE SEQUENCE seq_item;

CREATE TABLE Item (
    ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT nextval('seq_item'),
    SENDER INTEGER REFERENCES User(id),
    RECEIVER INTEGER REFERENCES User(id),
    INFO TEXT,
    BOX_ID INTEGER REFERENCES Box(id) NOT NULL,
    ARRIVAL TIMESTAMP
);
```

Its main use case is a typical producer/consumer scenario. Different users may insert an item in the database in a particular box for a particular user and each user can retrieve the topmost(this means the oldest) item in a box that is addressed to her/him. It more or less mimics the functionality of a queue on a database level.

More precisely, the most common operations are the following:

```
INSERT INTO ITEM(SENDER, RECEIVER, INFO, BOX_ID, ARRIVAL) 
VALUES (nsid, nrid, ncontent, nqid, ntime);
```

And retrieve commands based on a combination of either `RECEIVER+SENDER` or `RECEIVER+BOX_ID`:

```
SELECT * INTO it FROM Item i WHERE (i.RECEIVER=? OR i.RECEIVER is NULL) AND 
(i.BOX_ID=?) ORDER BY ARRIVAL LIMIT 1;
DELETE FROM Item i WHERE i.id=it.id;
```

and

```
SELECT * INTO it FROM Item i WHERE (i.RECEIVER=? OR i.RECEIVER is NULL) AND 
(i.SENDER=?) ORDER BY ARRIVAL LIMIT 1;
DELETE FROM Item i WHERE i.id=it.id;
```

The last two snippets are packed within a stored procedure.

I considered using two different indexes.

**1.** `CREATE INDEX ind ON item(arrival);`. The `EXPLAIN` plan for the aforementioned `SELECT` is the following:

```
Limit  (cost=0.29..2.07 rows=1 width=35)
  ->  Index Scan using ind on item i  (cost=0.29..3010.81 rows=1693 width=35)
        Filter: (((receiver = 2) OR (receiver IS NULL)) AND (sender = 2))
```

As far as I understand, the advantage of this approach is that I avoid sorting the data. However, as far as I understand, I still need to scan the whole table, but the access will be random and this will slow down the execution. What I am not sure is if the execution will stop as soon as a match is found because of `LIMIT 1` or it will always scan the whole table.

**2.** `CREATE INDEX ind ON item(receiver, sender);` The `EXPLAIN`:

```
Limit  (cost=512.23..512.23 rows=1 width=35)
  ->  Sort  (cost=512.23..516.46 rows=1693 width=35)
        Sort Key: arrival
        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on message m  (cost=42.37..503.76 rows=1693 width=35)
              Recheck Cond: (((receiver = 2) AND (sender = 2)) OR ((receiver IS NULL) AND (sender = 2)))
              ->  BitmapOr  (cost=42.37..42.37 rows=1693 width=0)
                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on ind  (cost=0.00..37.22 rows=1693 width=0)
                          Index Cond: ((receiver = 2) AND (sender = 2))
                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on ind  (cost=0.00..4.30 rows=1 width=0)
                          Index Cond: ((receiver IS NULL) AND (sender = 2))
```

In this scenario I can efficiently find the matches for a `receiver` and `sender`, but I need to sort the result afterwards, which may be slow.

So which of the two options is better and why? The estimated cost for the first is way lower, but the second one seems to be more "deterministic".

Comment: Which is better depends on the distribution of your data.  If your queries have few matches, then the `order by` is not a big performance hit.  If they have many matches, then it makes a big difference.

Comment: Before thinking about indexes, think about keys. To me it seems that {sender,box} and {receiver,box} are candidate keys. and {box} could be one too (you cannot send a box twice?) The nullability of sender and receiver looks suspect to me; can the sender send a box without a known receiver? (and/or vice versa)

Comment: @wildplasser, sorry for the confusion, but the example is obfuscated. Box is intended as a container where different items bay be stored. They are static, rarely change and are not unique along the rows. When the receiver is unknown, everyone can pick the corresponding item.

Comment: So, box is stable and unique and could be NOT NULL? Why are boxes not unique? Can a box be sent more than on time?

Comment: One can place plenty of items in the same box and for this reason they are not unique.

Comment: So a box can contain multiple items. But are these all addressed to the same reciever, or do these all stem from the same sender?

Comment: There are no restrictions about that. The sender and receiver may even be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this query:

```
SELECT * INTO it
FROM Item i
WHERE (i.RECEIVER = ? OR i.RECEIVER is NULL) AND 
      (i.SENDER = ?)
ORDER BY ARRIVAL
LIMIT 1;
```

The best index is likely to be `item(sender, arrival, receiver)`, in that order.  This will filter by sender, then use the index for ordering, and filter again by receiver.

The fastest way to go may be:

```
select *
from ((select i.*
       from item i
       where receiver = ? and sender = ?
       order by arrival
       limit 1
      ) union all
      (select i.*
       from item i
       where receiver is null and sender = ?
       order by arrival
       limit 1
      ) 
     ) i
order by arrival
limit 1;
```

The best index for this version is `item(sender, receiver, arrival)`.  It will use the index to fetch (at most) one row in each subquery.  The final sort (on two rows) is negligible.

Of course, the same reasoning applies to the other query as well.

Comment: Thank you very much for the thorough explanation!
So you suggest writing two separate indexes on `item(sender, receiver, arrival)` and `item(box_id, receiver, arrival)` ?
In addition, why is the union of the two faster than simply `(i.RECEIVER = ? OR i.RECEIVER is NULL) AND 
      (i.SENDER = ?)`?
Moreover, what do we achieve by including the `arrival` in the end? Will this improve the inner `order by`?

Comment: SQL optimizers often have a hard time with `OR` (I don't know if Postgres has a better optimizer).  The `arrival` at the end is for the `order by`.